# How to use @Builder(Lombok) in extended classes?

Tags: java, lombok

In my application I have simple classes:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class Message {
    private String id;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private String to;
    private String from;
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class MessageText extends Message{
    private String text;
}
```

I'm trying to create new MessageText using builder. without builder() in classic OOP style I can set al params, including parent's id, createdAt and etc.

```
MessageText responseMsg = new MessageText();
        responseMsg.setId("id");
        responseMsg.setText("Hello");
        responseMsg.setTo("to");
        responseMsg.setFrom("server");
        responseMsg.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
```

But unfortunately, when I want to do the same using builder, I can set only text field:

```
MessageText.builder()
                .text("Hello!")
                .build();
```

In such approach I cannot set parents params(id, form, to, createdAt)
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder